Trivial "lookup" type for struct
I have an expensive struct that I want to use as a key sometimes:
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct Cat {
    name: String,
    image: Image,
}

How can I define a simple "lookup" type for this expensive struct - i.e. a struct of references to each field type of the key struct?
This would be useful so I can have HashMap<Cat, V> and find(CatRef) -> &V. find(&Cat) is much worse, e.g. it would require instantiating a String even if there is a free &'static str available.
I could type it out myself like so, but I risk the "owning" type getting out of sync with the "reference" type:
struct CatRef<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    image: &'a Image,
}

// Implement Hash, etc. consistently with Cat


Do you really want the Image (I assume it's raster pixel data for an image) to be part of the hash map key? Or just the name field?

I just needed an example of a key that is expensive to construct. I agree that it's a little contrived.

Your plan to use CatRef to do lookups in HashMap<Cat, _> won't work because you wouldn't be able to implement Borrow<CatRef> for Cat. You'd need to use the dynamic trait object trick shown here: How to get value from HashMap with two keys via references to both keys?.

@kmdreko So the answer is "it is impossible" because Borrow<CatRef> for Cat would need to return a reference to a pre-existing CatRef, which cannot exist in Cat because it would make Cat self-referential, correct?

you probably want to use Cow here then

@Bamontan Probably use Cow and then implement the Hash trait with it.

What if you put both your "Key" and "Value" as the V of a lookup map and use the hash value of your "Key" as a handle for lookup,
that way you can store it in a BTreeMap, and only perform hashing once, which save some computation that might be expensive for large struct.
if you wish to use the large struct somewhere else in your program, you can simply use Rc<RefCell<_>> or Arc<Mutex<_>> as K in LookUpTable
Example
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Cat {
    pub name: String,
}

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::hash::{DefaultHasher, Hash, Hasher};
use std::marker::PhantomData;
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct LookUpTable<K: Hash, V> {
    map: BTreeMap<u64, (K, V)>,
    //            ^     ^  ^
    //            |     |  L hold the value
    //            |     L--- hold the key
    //            L--------- hold the handle for looking up
}

impl<K: Hash, V> LookUpTable<K, V> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        LookUpTable {
            map: Default::default(),
        }
    }
    pub fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> u64 {
        // get the hash value of K(the large struct)
        let handle = {
            let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
            key.hash(&mut s);
            s.finish()
        };

        // insertion
        self.map.insert(handle, (key, value));

        // return the handle for later use
        handle
    }
    pub fn update(&mut self, handle: u64, new_v: V) {
        self.map.get_mut(&handle).unwrap().1 = new_v;
    }

    pub fn get(&self, handle: u64) -> &(K, V) {
        self.map.get(&handle).unwrap()
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, handle: u64) -> &mut (K, V) {
        self.map.get_mut(&handle).unwrap()
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut table: LookUpTable<Cat, String> = LookUpTable::new();

    // create a new Cat instance
    let cat_1: Cat = Cat {
        name: "Cat 1".to_string(),
    };

    // --------------------------------------------------
    println!("\n\n{}", "-".repeat(50));
    println!("Empty Table");
    println!("{:#?}", table);

    // --------------------------------------------------
    println!("\n\n{}", "-".repeat(50));
    println!("Insertion");
    // insert the Cat into the table and get a handle back
    let cat_1_handle: u64 = table.insert(cat_1, "This is a value of cat 1.".to_string());
    println!("{:#?}", table);

    // --------------------------------------------------
    println!("\n\n{}", "-".repeat(50));
    println!("get()");
    {
        let (cat_1, value_1): &(Cat, String) = table.get(cat_1_handle);
        println!("cat 1   : {:?}", cat_1);
        println!("value 1 : {:?}", value_1);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
    println!("\n\n{}", "-".repeat(50));
    println!("update()");
    table.update(cat_1_handle, "This is a new value of cat 1.".to_string());
    println!("{:#?}", table);

    // --------------------------------------------------
    println!("\n\n{}", "-".repeat(50));
    println!("get_mut()");
    {
        let (cat_1, value_1): &mut (Cat, String) = table.get_mut(cat_1_handle);
        cat_1.name.push_str(": Mister Whisker");
        value_1.push_str(" Appended string at the end.");
    }

    println!("{:#?}", table);
}

Output
--------------------------------------------------
Empty Table
LookUpTable {
    map: {},
}


--------------------------------------------------
Insertion
LookUpTable {
    map: {
        16159386690693546360: (
            Cat {
                name: "Cat 1",
            },
            "This is a value of cat 1.",
        ),
    },
}


--------------------------------------------------
get()
cat 1   : Cat { name: "Cat 1" }
value 1 : "This is a value of cat 1."


--------------------------------------------------
update()
LookUpTable {
    map: {
        16159386690693546360: (
            Cat {
                name: "Cat 1",
            },
            "This is a new value of cat 1.",
        ),
    },
}


--------------------------------------------------
get_mut()
LookUpTable {
    map: {
        16159386690693546360: (
            Cat {
                name: "Cat 1: Mister Whisker",
            },
            "This is a new value of cat 1. Appended string at the end.",
        ),
    },
}

Extra
Since the handle is just u64, to avoid misuse of it you can wrap it around another struct like this:
pub struct LookUpTableHandle<T> {
    _handle: u64,
    _p: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<K: Hash, V> LookUpTable<K,V> {
    pub fn insert_key_value(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> LookUpTableHandle<Self> {
        let _handle = {
            let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
            key.hash(&mut s);
            s.finish()
        };

        self.map.insert(_handle, (key, value));

        LookUpTableHandle { _handle, _p: PhantomData::default() }
    }
    pub fn get_by_handle(&mut self, handle: &LookUpTableHandle<Self>) -> &(K,V) {
        self.map.get(&handle._handle).unwrap()
    }
}

// usage
{
    let cat_2 = Cat{name: "Cat 2".to_string()};
    let handle: LookUpTableHandle<LookUpTable<Cat, String>> = table.insert_key_value(cat_2, "Some String".to_string());
}


What about hash collisions?

It just use the hash of the Cat struct like a normal HashMap, if the two hash is the same that probably mean that it is two same object (unless the hash implementation is faulty or really really really rare case).

A HashMap uses hashes to speed up lookup, but it still performs a complete equality check in the end, and it deals well with hash collisions. This approach might work in some specific situations, but this leaves a very obscure bug/vulnerability in the program.

This code uses hash. The handle IS the hash of the Cat that was inserted. You can still perform a complete equality check and hash collision handling in the insert() function.
